# Changing the color of certain rows in a table - wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a table in which i want to make the column 1,3,4 filled in with this color
"#e1e1e1". How may i do so?

https://www.sebuys.com/shop/windows-10-customised-i7-i5-7th-gen-rgb-gaming-tower-16gb-8gb-ddr4-pc-computer/

[image: table]

Comment: Check out the nth-child selector: https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

Comment: @FAKETAXI you need to make that an answer.  It is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the nth-child selector: http://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies

```css
td:nth-child(1),
td:nth-child(3),
td:nth-child(4){
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Col 1</td>
      <td>Col 2</td>
      <td>Col 3</td>
      <td>Col 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Col 1</td>
      <td>Col 2</td>
      <td>Col 3</td>
      <td>Col 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Col 1</td>
      <td>Col 2</td>
      <td>Col 3</td>
      <td>Col 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Col 1</td>
      <td>Col 2</td>
      <td>Col 3</td>
      <td>Col 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi Sir, actually that is applicable for lists but not tables (td). Can yoiu please provide some https://www.sebuys.com/shop/windows-10-customised-i7-i5-7th-gen-rgb-gaming-tower-16gb-8gb-ddr4-pc-computer/

Comment: @codeisfun1234 it's definitely applicable. I've added an example for you.